# Set a value to global variable from a subshell

Tags: bash, function, shell, global-variables, zsh

Code example `main.zsh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

. ./my_script.zsh

my_global_var=""

output=$(my_func)
```

Code example `my_script.zsh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

my_func(){
    my_global_var="hello!" # doesn't work!
    echo "my output" # return value
}
```

In this case how can I set a value to `my_global_var` from `my_func` in a subshell. What I try to do here, I just try to implement a function concept in `zsh` which be able to return a value via variable substitution mechanism `$()` but the problem is if I implement it in this way, I will not be able to access global variable from my function. I'm quite confusing now, maybe I get into the wrong way to implement a function concept in `zsh`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. `my_func` runs in a separate process, so whatever it does to `my_global_var` is local to that process, unseen by `main.zsh`. Your function can either be used to set global variables or output text intended to be captured by `$(...)`, not both.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, by the way, what is a best practice for dealing with a function in bash script? In programming languages such as C, Java are easily to deal with this kind of thing but how about bash?

Comment: Shell was never intended as a data-processing language; rather, it's a glue language for combining the functionality of other programs together. As such, a shell function should be thought of as a subroutine or a separate program, rather than something that computes and returns a result.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @chepner for your answer, BTW, I would like to purpose an alternative way to solve this problem. Many people have talked about "return multiple variables", in the same way, here I will purpose you an "eval trick"

Code example main.zsh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

. ./my_script.zsh

my_global_var=""
output=""

temp=$(my_func)
eval $(echo $temp) # become: set_vars "hello!" "my output"
```

Code example my_script.zsh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

my_func(){
    echo 'my_global_var="hello!"; output="my output"' # return values
}
```

Comment: If you are setting the value of two global parameters, you don't need `eval`; `my_func () { my_global_var="hello!"; output="my output"; }` does the same thing.

Comment: I think so, how stupid am I, but anyway, I think this trick may useful in some problem.

Comment: @fronthem @chepner The use case for eval is when you want to use a subshell instead of a function; example: eval $(echo output='`date`'; echo 'var3="variable3"')